# External HDD locks Windows XP

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive

I have [1TB Seagate Portable External Hard Drive STAX1000102](http://www.microcenter.com/product/373123/Expansion_1TB_SuperSpeed_USB_30_Portable_External_Hard_Drive). When I attach it (USB) to the laptop (Dell Latitude D530) with Windows XP version 2002 SP3, the Operation System goes into strange state. I cannot run simple app like Total Commander, I cannot just do even simple operations, I cannot browse in already launched web browser, I can do nothing - everything takes forever. I cannot even shut down the computer - it must be done by the laptop on/off button. It is not consuming a lot of CPU nor a lot of HDD - it seems that the Operation System itself gets locked somehow.

Just by [simply running msconfig](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/quickly-remove-items-from-windows-xp-startup/), I disabled all items in the *Startup* tab, all non-Microsoft items in *Services* tab, and the issue is still present! I also tried to disable some of the Microsoft services, but it didn't help either. Only thing that helped was to run Windows in safe mode.

The HDD works fine on many other laptops and desktop PCs.

Do  you have any idea what could cause the trouble?

#### EDIT - result of @STTR's script:

I have run your script (usbrest.cmd) and unfortunatelly it didn't help. Here is the output (unfortunatelly I have localised Win, I will try to translate where needed):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas> C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}" /v LowerFilters /f

Chyba:  Systém nenalezl zadaný klíč registru nebo požadovanou hodnotu.
(translation: error: registry key or value not found)

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}" /v UpperFilters /f

Chyba:  Systém nenalezl zadaný klíč registru nebo požadovanou hodnotu.
(translation: error: registry key or value not found)

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Class\{4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}" /v LowerFilters /f

Chyba:  Systém nenalezl zadaný klíč registru nebo požadovanou hodnotu.
(translation: error: registry key or value not found)

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>del /F /A:- %windir%\inf\INFCACHE.1

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config stisvc start= auto [SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start stisvc

SERVICE_NAME: stisvc
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE,NOT_PAUSABLE,IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 1540
        FLAGS              :

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config ShellHWDetection start= auto 
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start ShellHWDetection 
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu
```

I have been also looking at the registry key you have mentioned but I have not found the `LowerFilters`, `UpperFilters` values.

#### EDIT 2, output of STTR's script `getusb-file.cmd`:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>dir /B /A:- %windir%\system32\Drivers\usb*
usb8023.sys
usb8023x.sys
usbcamd.sys
usbcamd2.sys
usbccgp.sys
usbd.sys
usbehci.sys
usbhub.sys
usbintel.sys
usbohci.sys
usbport.sys
usbstor.sys
usbuhci.sys
usbvideo.sys

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>dir /B /A:- %windir%\inf\usb* | find /i ".inf"
usb.inf
usbport.inf
usbprint.inf
usbstor.inf
usbvideo.inf

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
```

#### EDIT 3:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>wmic BASEBOARD get Product, SerialNumber, Version, Manufacturer
Chyba: (= error)
Kód = 0x80070422
Popis = Zvolenou službu nelze spustit, protože není povolena nebo s ní není spojeno žádné povolené zařízení. (= The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.)
Prostředek = Win32



F:\sw\pstools>REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE103??18}" /v UpperFilters

Chyba:  Systém nenalezl zadaný klíč registru nebo požadovanou hodnotu.
(= registry key or value was not found)
```

I have dumped whole [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class registry](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~ttel5535/pub/so/registry.reg) for you to see.

#### EDIT 4

Here is the output of RestoreServiceSetting.cmd (there were some errors):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::HID Input Service
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config HidServ start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start HidServ
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Shell Hardware Detection
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config ShellHWDetection start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start ShellHWDetection
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config stisvc start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start stisvc
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Windows Management Instrumentation
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config winmgmt start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start winmgmt

SERVICE_NAME: winmgmt
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE,NOT_PAUSABLE,IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 1796
        FLAGS              :

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Remote Registry
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config RemoteRegistry start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start RemoteRegistry

SERVICE_NAME: RemoteRegistry
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE,NOT_PAUSABLE,IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 2000
        FLAGS              :

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Logical Disk Manager
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config dmserver start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start dmserver

SERVICE_NAME: dmserver
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE,NOT_PAUSABLE,IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 1796
        FLAGS              :

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Logical Disk Manager Administrative Service
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config dmadmin start= demand
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS
```

After restart:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>wmic BASEBOARD get Product, SerialNumber, Version, Manufacturer
Manufacturer  Product  SerialNumber              Version
Dell Inc.     0HP728   .721HP3J.CN4864383F5721.
```

#### EDIT5:

After running `secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secsetup.inf /db secsetup.sdb /verbose` and 
`secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secDC.inf /db secDC.sdb /verbose` I got this output (translated, commented):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secsetup.inf /db secsetup.sdb /verbose

Úloha je dokončena. Některé soubory uvedené v konfiguraci nebyly v tomto systému
 nalezeny, nelze tedy nastavit ani zjišťovat zabezpečení. Zprávu můžete ignorova
t.
Podrobnosti naleznete v souboru %windir%\security\logs\scesrv.log.
(task is finished. Some of the files were not found so the security level cannot be
 found out. You can ignore this. Details in the scesrv.log -- actually this command
 took quite a long time, showing progress in percent)

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secDC.inf /db secDC.sdb /verbose

Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor.

Úloha byla dokončena s chybou.
Podrobnosti naleznete v souboru %windir%\security\logs\scesrv.log.
(File was not found -- the secDC.in does not exist. THis terminated immediatelly.
 The log file just said that the secDC.inf file could not be found.)
```

Then I rebooted and the problem persisted. So I hard-rebooted and tried RestoreServiceSetting.cmd script again, but there were similar errors as in the last run:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::HID Input Service
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config HidServ start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start HidServ
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Shell Hardware Detection
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config ShellHWDetection start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start ShellHWDetection
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config stisvc start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start stisvc
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Windows Management Instrumentation
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config winmgmt start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start winmgmt
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Remote Registry
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config RemoteRegistry start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start RemoteRegistry
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Logical Disk Manager
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config dmserver start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc start dmserver
[SC] StartService FAILED 1056:

Instance tÚto slu

C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>::Logical Disk Manager Administrative Service
C:\Documents and Settings\Tomas>sc config dmadmin start= demand
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS
```

I connected the drive again and the problem still persists.

**EDIT:** today I tried to attach normal (internal) HDD using the USB adapter and it did lock the computer the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a problem in the Keys:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

`LowerFilters`, `UpperFilters` value.

and as variant:

mountpoint:

```
mountvol /L | find "\\"
```

mountpoint, registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices
```

remove unwanted entries mount points:

[image: remove unwanted entries mount points]

USB ID device:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR
```

## Windows XP:

backup registry and run:

usbrest.cmd:

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}" /v LowerFilters /f
REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}" /v UpperFilters /f
REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}" /v LowerFilters /f
del /F /A:- %windir%\inf\INFCACHE.1
sc config stisvc start= auto
sc start stisvc
sc config ShellHWDetection start= auto
sc start ShellHWDetection
```

need reboot.

usbdevice-delete-all.cmd:

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB" /f
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR" /f
```

## delete all USB at device:

```
psexec -i -d -s usbdevice-delete-all.cmd
```

## [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

need reboot.

## Run in `cmd`, getusb-file.cmd

getusb-file.cmd:

```
dir /B /A:- %windir%\system32\Drivers\usb*
dir /B /A:- %windir%\inf\usb* | find /i ".inf"
```

## Run in `cmd` get UpperFilters disk device:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}" /v UpperFilters
```

## Run in `cmd`, get systemboard info:

```
wmic BASEBOARD get Product, SerialNumber, Version, Manufacturer
```

Output:

```
Manufacturer           Product  SerialNumber     Version
ASUSTeK Computer INC.  P5Q      MS1C8CBKC500124  Rev 1.xx
```

RestoreServiceSetting.cmd:

```
::HID Input Service
sc config HidServ start= auto
sc start HidServ

::Shell Hardware Detection
sc config ShellHWDetection start= auto
sc start ShellHWDetection

::Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)
sc config stisvc start= auto
sc start stisvc

::Windows Management Instrumentation
sc config winmgmt start= auto
sc start winmgmt

::Remote Registry
sc config RemoteRegistry start= auto
sc start RemoteRegistry

::Logical Disk Manager
sc config dmserver start= auto
sc start dmserver

::Logical Disk Manager Administrative Service
sc config dmadmin start= demand
```

usbrest2.cmd:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}" /v UpperFilters /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d PartMgr\0 /f
```

Disables automatic mounting of new volumes:

```
mountvol /N
```

Re-enables automatic mounting of new volumes:

```
mountvol /E
```

Restore default registry and filesystem settings:

```
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secsetup.inf /db secsetup.sdb /verbose
secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secDC.inf /db secDC.sdb /verbose
```

See eventlog disk event:

```
powershell Get-Eventlog system -Source Disk
```

See 10 last disk error:

```
powershell Get-Eventlog system -newest 10 -EntryType Error -Source Disk
```

Comment: thank you! I have tried your script but it didn't help. Please have a look at my updated answer, I posted the output of your script.

Comment: @Tomas Update, use `usbdevice-delete-all.cmd`, need reboot. If this step fails, then the problem in a number of missing files. Write the result. Thank you!

Comment: STTR, thanks! I have run the script. I don't know why but I got "access denied"! And I am Administrator!

Comment: @Tomas run `psexec -i -d -s usbdevice-delete-all.cmd`, download `psexec`. See link at answer. Updated!

Comment: thank you STTR, I have run the script using `psexec` (haven't seen the output; it was run in newly opened window which just flashed), restarted and connected the drive, and the problem persists. I couldn't even send this comment to you; I needed to save it (on USB flash), and hard reboot. I also forgot to mention that the drive doesn't get properly mounted. Connecting to different USB port didn't help either.

Comment: @Tomas Run in `cmd` getusb-file.cmd. Post output in your question plz!

Comment: @Tomas Usb file list - Ok. Connect HDD in USB port 3, 2 ? USB cable mark?
Run in `cmd` commands: `wmic BASEBOARD get Product, SerialNumber, Version, Manufacturer`
and `REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}" /v UpperFilters`
Post report. Thx!

Comment: STTR, thanks for your persistence! I have run your script and posted the result. I think the USB is v2, not v3. How do I know? It is Dell Latitude D530. USB cable mark - does it matter? I use two connected together - one possibly from Seagate (shipped with HDD) and the other blue one with letters CBL.

Comment: @Tomas run in `cmd` file `RestoreServiceSetting.cmd` and `usbrest2.cmd`. Reboot. After reboot run `wmic BASEBOARD get Product, SerialNumber, Version, Manufacturer` in `cmd`

Comment: STTR if you don't mind I prefer to continue in comments, as I am not always online... and chat will be deleted later on, the progress will not be trackable after 1, 2, 12 months...

Comment: @Tomas Yes, of course. USB cable makes a difference. Try a good cable standard USB 2.0. You can also use the USB 3.0 cable to connect to two sockets.
Low amperage USB connectors can also cause connectivity problems.

Comment: STTR, thanks. I have done as you told me and posted the output. I tried to connect the HDD again but the problem persists.

Comment: @Tomas I'll think about how to collect the full diagnostics on your system. And then we'll do something else. +3 days. Thank you!

Comment: @Tomas Based on the 1056 error I think there is a problem with the permissions on the file system and registry. Let us restore all default settings. The process is quite long, up to several hours. In `cmd` run: `secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secsetup.inf /db secsetup.sdb /verbose` and `secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\repair\secDC.inf /db secDC.sdb /verbose`

Comment: STTR, what do you mean by "restore all default settings" - to restore all the changes we have made together, or to restore to some post-installation state or what? Couldn't this harm the installed programs somehow? The computer is not mine and I don't want to break the applications installed here.

Comment: @Tomas http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313222

Comment: STTR, I am afraid to do this on computer, which is not mine... Nevertheless thank you very much for your persistence and will to help!

Comment: @Tomas On that machine problem with the services and the strange setting. Not surprisingly, there is a problem with external devices. Thank you. It was interesting.

Comment: STTR, I have run your script and the RestoreServiceSetting.cmd script again, please see updated answer (EDIT 5). Unfortunatelly the problem still persists.